# What is a tensorflow session actually?

Tags: session, tensorflow, definition

What does the sentence below quoted from getting started with tensorflow mean?

> A session encapsulates the control and state of the TensorFlow runtime.

I know encapsulation in object oriented programming, and also have played with session a bit with success. Still I do not get this sentence very well. Can someone rephrase it in simple words?

Comment: In this context, "encapsulates" roughly means "contains." It's not about OOP encapsulation - just that the session maintains all of the data that's required to determine the current state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This encapsulation has nothing to do with OOP encapsulation. A slightly better (in terms of understanding for a new-comer) definition is in [session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) documentation.

> A Session object encapsulates the environment in which Operation
>   objects are executed, and Tensor objects are evaluated.

Which means that none the operators and variables defined in the graph-definition part are being executed. For example nothing is being executed/calculated here

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3], stddev=1.)
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3], stddev=1.)
c = a + b
```

You will not get the values of a tensors `a/b/c` now. There values will be evaluated only inside of the Session.

Answer (score 8):

Like Dali said, the encapsulation has nothing to do with OOP encapsulation.

> the **control** and **state** of the TensorFlow runtime

**the control:** A TensorFlow graph is a description of computations. To compute anything, a graph must be launched in a Session.

**state:** A Session places the graph ops onto Devices, such as CPUs or GPUs, and provides methods to execute them. These methods return tensors produced by ops as numpy ndarray objects in Python, and as tensorflow::Tensor instances in C and C++.